# Is there an updated firefox in the Ubuntu 14.04 repository?

Tags: firefox

I have Ubuntu 14.04

I was on firefox 39 and wanted the latest 53. I uninstalled 39 and tried to install the latest from tarball download.

I couldn't be bothered with all the simlinks and terminal stuff so I looked to reinstall from the repository but it only gave me firefox 28.

Why only firefox 28?
What's the most up-to-date firefox I can install from repository?

Comment: The current one from the repository for me on 14.04 is 53.0.2... are you running `sudo apt-get update` before you try to install? (or since you've already installed the package now, `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`)?

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the *full, verbatim* output of `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -f`? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster could you please explain `-f`? I looked at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto and only saw `apt-get -f install`. Even `man apt-get` limits `-f` to "This option, when used with install/remove"

Comment: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/firefox.1.html shows `firefox_28.0+build2-0ubuntu2_i386` so I'm assuming that that is the version 14.04 initially offered. In a properly functioning system, you should have the latest, which is v53, as others have pointed out.

Comment: @DKBose: I added `-f` in case there's a package management issue that blocks all package upgrades. Your quote doesn't restricts it to the "install" and "remove" commands; it describes a special behaviour for these commands.

Comment: [According to Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox) v28.0+build2-0ubuntu2 is still the default Firefox version in Trusty if you don't enable security updates. Please enable security updates (see below).

Answer (score 3):

[According to Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox) v28.0+build2-0ubuntu2 is still the default Firefox version in Trusty if you don't enable security updates. Please enable security updates (see below)!

1. Open *System Settings > Software & Updates* or run `software-properties-gtk` and go to the tab labelled *Updates*.
2. Enable the checkbox in front of *Important security updates (trusty-security)*:

   [image: software properties > updates]
3. A dialogue will ask you to enter your password to confirm this action because it requires super-user privileges.
4. Open *Update Manager* or run `update-manager`. This should update the package repository information and subsequently prompt you to install available package upgrades. There's also a list of available upgrades and the most recent Firefox version should be among them.

   [image: Update Manager]

   <sup>The picture is of an old version but the layout should be almost identical</sup>